# Values passed through an array pointer, changes all the values before index i to the new value being added at index i

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am having two main problems. First when I do baggy->add(40) it changes the value at data[0] and data[1](it is supposed to change this one only) to 40. 
When I do baggy->add(50) it changes the values at data[0] data[1] and data[2] (supposed to do this one only) to 50.

I am no idea why. When I debug it shows that the address value at data[0] data[1] and data[2] are all the same address.

Also when I use baggy->Size it resets the values in the data array to 0.

This is my main.cpp

```
int main() {
BAG<int> *baggy;
baggy = new BAG<int>();
baggy->add(30);
baggy->add(40);
baggy->add(50);
//cout << baggy->Size << endl;
int num = *(*baggy).data[0];
int num2 = *(*baggy).data[1];
int num3 = *(*baggy).data[2];
cout << num << " " << num2 << " " << num3 << endl;

}
```

Header File

```
template <typename type>

class BAG {
public:
type *data[4];
void add(type item);
bool isEmpty();
int Size;
```

};

BAG.cpp

```
template <typename type>
void BAG<type>::add(type item){

if (sizeof(data) == (Size+1)){
    type *temp[2* sizeof(data)];
    for(int i=0;i<Size;i++){
        temp[i] = data[i];
    }
    *data = *temp;

}
    data[Size++] = &item;

}
template <typename type>
bool BAG<type>::isEmpty() {return Size == 0;}

template class BAG<int>;
```

Comment: Why do you create the BAG with `new`?

Comment: can you explain the block inside the `if (sizeof(data) == (Size+1))` ? It looks weird

Comment: By `&item` you store the address of a variable that stops existing when that function returns. Also you probably write out of bounds of `data`.  Your code would get much simpler and easier if you stop using pointers

Comment: I wouldn't need to use new to create a new object Neil?
I am using a fixed sized array, so if the array is full, it will create a new array twice as big.
Thanks M.M. I am getting used to the whole pointer situation in C++. I am not sure if I can get around pointers.